# Count occurences

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrays

I would like to make a **count based on fulfilling two conditions in a column across a range of columns**. For the sake of easily explaining things, I have decided to make a table of names and foods, I've added days as well, but they are not relevant and here only to help me describe my problem.

Is there a way, to count f.e. how many times Antony has eaten pizza on different days (or better said, Antony and pizza have occured in the same column across a range) and do that for hamburger and hot dog as well. Repeat that for Derek, Iva and others.

I have tried mapping numbers and implementing lambda, but I am really not experienced with it and all my attempts of comming up with something that will work have ended in vain.

Hope my explanation is clear, I would appreciate if anyone could help me solve my problem.

**The numbers in "Data" were added manually.*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### COUNTIF & FILTER

- The [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480) function returns a conditional count across a range;
  `=COUNTIF(range, criterion)`
- The [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) function returns a filtered version of the source range, returning only rows or columns that meet the specified conditions.
  `=FILTER(range, condition1, [condition2, ...])`
- By combining [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480) & [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) one can [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) the data across all days based on a `menu` item, then use [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480) to count occurrences of a `name` in the filtered data.

##### Named Ranges in Formulas

The formula can be adapted for a LAMBDA function

| name | range | note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| _mealdata | `F2:O2` | **Daily meals** data entries |
| _namedata | `F3:O7` | **Daily names** data entries |
| _namelist | `A2:A7` | **List of names** for filtering data |
| _meallist | `B1:D1` | **List of meals** for filtering data |

##### First Formula

Formula uses named ranges to make the code easier to manage.

```
=COUNTIF(FILTER(_namedata, _mealdata=B$1), $A2)
```

[image]

##### LAMBDA Function

```
=BYROW(_namelist, LAMBDA(n, MAP(_meallist, LAMBDA(m, COUNTIF(FILTER(_namedata,_mealdata=m),n)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know if this option would be easier, but for me the formula

`=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF($E$4:$J$9=$A4,N($E$3:$J$3=B$3),0)))`

placed in cell **B4** and then stretched over the entire range **B4:D9** gave the same result as that of our respected colleagues ***Blind Spots*** and ***doubleunary***

Comment: Thank you ever so much, it works as desired as well!

Answer (score 0):

To collect the data, use string concatenation, `flatten()` and `split()` in an array formula. To aggregate and pivot the data, use `query()` with a `pivot` clause, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    split( flatten(E4:N & "→" & E3:N3), "→", false, false), 
    "select Col1, count(Col1) 
     where Col1 is not null 
     group by Col1 
     pivot Col2", 
    0 
  ) 
)
```

The formula above is an array formula that will create the whole result table, complete with headers, in one go.

The results look like this:

| Results |  |  |  | Data |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **Hamburger** | **Hotdog** | **Pizza** | Pizza | Hamburger | Hotdog | Pizza | Pizza | Hotdog |
| **Antony** | 1 | 1 | 3 | Antony | Mia | Iva | Antony | Iva | Josh |
| **Derek** | 1 |  | 3 | Derek | Antony | John | Derek | John | Mia |
| **Iva** |  | 1 | 3 | Iva | Derek | Josh | Iva | Mia | Antony |
| **John** |  | 1 | 3 | John |  |  | John | Antony |  |
| **Josh** |  | 2 | 2 | Josh |  |  | Josh | Derek |  |
| **Mia** | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

See [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343), [split()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) and [flatten()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761).

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, it works well and it gave me another viewpoint on how to manipulate data.